# Using CreateView with 2 Models at the same time

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

should I be building a function to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `form_valid()` method of CreateView. This is called if, well, your form is valid. Then you can create your SetAmount instance there.

## Single Exercise Instance

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # Easy way to obtain the through model (aka SetAmount)
    SetAmount = WorkoutRoutine.exercise.through
    # Assuming the exercise is selected in the form
    exercise = form.cleaned_data['exercise']
    # Create a SetAmount instance with the correct workout_routine and exercise from the form
    SetAmount.objects.create(
        workout_routine=form.instance,
        # exercise is a QuerySet, first() will get the instance
        exercise=exercise.first(),
        set_amount=100 # Swole
    )
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

## Multiple Exercise Instances with `bulk_create`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # Easy way to obtain the through model (aka SetAmount)
    SetAmount = WorkoutRoutine.exercise.through
    # Assuming the exercise is selected in the form
    exercises = form.cleaned_data['exercise']
    # Bulk create relationships by building a list comprehension with exercises cleaned data and passing the list to bulk_create())
    SetAmount.objects.bulk_create([
        SetAmount(
            workout_routine=form.instance,
            exercise=exercise,
            set_amount=100 # Swole
        ) for exercise in exercises
    ])
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew it shouldn't be too complicated!  Lots to learn.

Comment: Hey I gave this a try and I am struggling.  When I select an exercise it says "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'instance'"

Comment: `form` shouldn't be a queryset, are you accessing the `instance` attribute anywhere else or just with `form.instance`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The error message above is when I tried exercise=exercise.instance.  When I try it with exercise=exercise I get there error: "Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Exercise: Overhead Press>]>": "SetAmount.exercise" must be a "Exercise" instance."

Comment: Ahh right, so since exercise is a MtM field on WorkoutRoutine your form's cleaned data for that field will return a queryset instead of a single instance even if you only selected a single exercise. Should you be able to add multiple exercises to a workout routine from the form? Likely you'll want that eventually. But in this case you're creating the single relationship so you need to get the instance from the queryset with something like `exercise=exercise.first()`. Look into using `bulk_create()` instead of `create()` for quickly adding multiple through relations if desired.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show the difference between adding single and multiple exercise relationships and correcting the queryset issue. If you only want to allow a single exercise to be submitted you would need to handle that in the form validation, either in `form_valid()` above or by creating a custom model form and overriding its `clean()` or `clean_<field_name>()` methods.

Comment: Awesome.  Adding more than 1 exercise at a time was the next step, which I have implemented with check boxes.  Much appreciated!!